# Open source real life license examples: yours or others

Tags: java, php, open-source, licensing

I'm aware of the usual list of open source licenses, so I'm not even going to list it here.

What I'd like to ask is about your open source projects (whether out or planned for the future), and why you're planning to choose a certain license over the other. Basically say I went for X license because I wanted Y and that other license didn't provide it for  me.

I understand that the language itself can make a difference in the choice of license: **interpreted languages like PHP vs. compiled languages like Java. I'm mostly interested in hearing about PHP projects, but of course additional insights are welcome. You may even have chosen that particular language for a licensing reason.**

Ideally I want to hear answers from people who were involved in the actual project (i.e. your own project), because that usually means you've put some thought into the license yourself and understand the implications of that license. But examples of existing projects that aren't your own are OK. Please just say why you think that license was good/bad for them. But first-hand experience is preferred.

Looking forward to hearing some informative input.

Comment: Specific examples are still welcome, and please also see this related question: Why open source? and how to get real involvement? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613677/why-open-source-it-and-how-to-get-real-involvement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use GPL if you want to sell a non-open source version and/or do not want others to use it in their commerical products.

Use MIT license if you want everybody, everywhere to be able to use your code.

Use Apache license otherwise.

Comment: I like this answer: very to the point, you're obviously not a lawyer! :)

Comment: I thought Apache was like MIT, no?

Comment: Hi Thorbjørn, I'm just curious, but what exactly is the difference between MIT license and Apache license?

Comment: This was discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40100/apache-licence-vs-bsd-vs-mit: